# curl command to replace existing folder

Tags: curl, tfs, jfrog-cli

I am using JFrog to store all the artifacts. I am using curl cmd to replace the artifact.
Below is the curl cmd, the problem it doesn't replace/ overwrite the 'WINX64.zip'.

```
curl -X PUT -u user1:$(pwd) http://xyz:8080/artifactory/xyzFolder/winx64/WINX64.zip 
 -T  C:\artifacts\localMachine\Test.zip -v
```

Please correct me on curl, I am not familiar with this cmd.

To give additional Info, I am updating this from tfs build. I am not familiar TFS JFrogDeployer. Basically whenever build is completed, I want the WINX64.zip from above path to be updated everytime build is completed. It can be curl or by any other method.

Hope I am clear, anymore Info please do me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following curl script:

```
curl -u username:password -X PUT "http://localhost:8046/artifactory/xxx/windows.zip" -T filepath/xxx.zip
```

Here is my example in build:

Orgin artifact:

[image]

Build definition:

[image]

Artifacts can be generated in the previous tasks in `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.
Then i use the curl command to upload the artifacts to jfrog.

The existing zip file will be replaced.

[image]

On the other hand, you also could use this Azure Devops extension: [JFrog Artifactory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension) to upload the files.

Here is the doc about [Jfrog Rest API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Artifactory TFS Extension.](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Azure%20DevOps%20and%20TFS%20Artifactory%20Extension)

It will allow you to easily upload files using the [upload task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Azure%20DevOps%20and%20TFS%20Artifactory%20Extension#AzureDevOpsandTFSArtifactoryExtension-UploadingGenericArtifactstoArtifactory).